# manytomany retrieve Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have @manytomany relation in hibernate
Like :
Table Employee

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
}
```

Table Role :

```
public class Role implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private long id;
}
```

how to get all employee when role have a specific value by **hibernate Criterion**
or subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the try JB Nizet's answer and return multiple row not the same number in table 
the solution is to add setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)

```
Criteria c = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Employee.class,"employee");
c.createAlias("employee.roles", "role");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("role.id", id));
List<Employee> employeed = c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to get all employees having a specific role. Why use the Criteria API for this. HQL is much simpler and readable:

```
select e from Employee e inner join e.roles role where role.id = :roleId
```

If you really want to use the Criteria API, here it goes:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Employee.class, "employee");
c.createAlias("employee.roles", "role");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("role.id", roleId));
List<Employee> employeed = c.list();
```